# Why is my model of image classification not working properly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I found some pictures at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8618866/ under DL_data there are 50x50 png images i want to use for a prediction of bagger or nobagger like this

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
print ("1")
model = keras.models.load_model('bagger_nobagger_png.h5')
img_path = "Bagger_Patch_094745_1_19492575.png" # change this to the path of your PNG file
img = image.load_img(img_path,target_size=(50, 50), color_mode='grayscale')
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = x / 65535.0 # normalize pixel values to [0,1] for PNG images
classes = model.predict(x)
print(classes)  # a value close to 0 means "bagger", a value close to 1 means "nobagger"
img_path = "C:/Users/hdorn/Desktop/Extra/noBagger/noBagger_Patch_Wind_1_200_2851.png" # change this to the path of your PNG file
img = image.load_img(img_path,target_size=(50, 50), color_mode='grayscale')
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = x / 65535.0 # normalize pixel values to [0,1] for PNG images
classes = model.predict(x)
print(classes)  # a value close to 0 means "bagger", a value close to 1 means "nobagger"
```

i used this to fit the model

```
import os
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
train_dir = "/Downloads/sensors-21-07527-s001 (1)/Data_and_Code_sensors-1424304/DL/DL_Data/Train"
validation_dir = "/Downloads/sensors-21-07527-s001 (1)/Data_and_Code_sensors-1424304/DL/DL_Data/validate"
# Define the ImageDataGenerator for data augmentation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
rotation_range=40,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
# Define the generator for training data
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
target_size=(50, 50),
color_mode='grayscale',
batch_size=20,
class_mode='binary')
# Define the generator for validation data
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir,
target_size=(50, 50),
color_mode='grayscale',
batch_size=20,
class_mode='binary')
# Define the model architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(50, 50, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.0001),
loss='binary_crossentropy',
metrics=['acc'])
# Train the model
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=100,
epochs=3,
validation_data=validation_generator,
validation_steps=50)

model.save('bagger_nobagger_png.h5')
```

But i always get a prediction around 50 %
What am i doing wrong

My files look like this

```
--DL_Data

------------Train

-------------------bagger

------------------------------bagger1.png

------------------------------xxxxxxxx.png

-------------------nobagger

------------------------------nobagger1.png

------------------------------zzzzzzzzzzzz.png

------------validate

-------------------bagger

------------------------------bagger9000.png

------------------------------nnnnnnnnnn.png

-------------------nobagger

------------------------------nobagger9000.png
------------------------------yyyyyyyyyyyyyy.png
```

I expected to get a prediction of around 0 for bagger or close to 1 for nobagger. But I always get a result around 0.5. I tried changing parameters of training and validation but it didnt help.

Comment: The normalization is not the same, dividing by 255 vs by 65535.

Answer (score 0):

In your generators you rescale the images by 1/255. However when you are doing predictions you rescale then as 1/65535. Change the later to 1/255 and things should predict properly.

Comment: now it outputs around 1 for both options
`1/1 [==============================] - 0s 173ms/step
[[0.9946461]]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 40ms/step
[[0.9948918]]`